# Error creating Media Player; Java, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

Well i know, that there are 2 results of `MediaPlayer.create()` function: created stream or `null`, and in this case i get the second one result. Got some thoughts about file path, but still don't know where i'm wrong. (Trying to play a random track from assets folder). Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button play36 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.threesix);


    String[] listOfFiles = new String[0];
    try {
        listOfFiles = getAssets().list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        int itemIndex = (int) (Math.random() * listOfFiles.length);
        String file = listOfFiles[itemIndex];
        String filePath = "file:///android_asset/".concat(file);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(filePath);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri);

        play36.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: `listOfFiles = getAssets().list("");`

Comment: in assets folder there are 2 `mp3` files

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Do me a favor, post the entire MainActivity.class file source code. Your error is coming from somewhere other than what you’ve posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and i too got that exception i have modified the code. You can try it. It is working on my device

```
                    String[] listOfFiles = new String[0];
                    try {
                        listOfFiles = getAssets().list("");
                        //  int itemIndex = (int) (Math.random() * listOfFiles.length);
                        int itemIndex = 1;
                        String file = listOfFiles[itemIndex];
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd(file);

                        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

NOTE: I have commented the random itemIndex because assets folder contain other things too. Like i had these in my folder so mind this thing.

[image]

For this you can limit the random number generation to number of your audio files in assets folder.

Comment: It might be stupid, but what is `holder` in your code? Literally don't have any clue(

Comment: Thank you a lot, anyway i can play media from assets folder now, but i have to remove `holder.mView.getContext().` because of unresolved symbol. What lib should i import? Because at this moments it works only with `getAssets()`.

Comment: Ohh thats my mistake, actually i was trying it my existing music player code. And just copied paste in my RecyclerviewAdapter. To get the context i need to use the ViewHolder view i.e., `holder.mView.getContext()`

Comment: @Huge_Noob you dont need to use getcontext() as you are using it in activity itself. i am updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the way you are setting your file path in the `MediaPlayer`. Since the file is in the assets directory, you shouldn't try to set the file path as a Uri in the `MediaPlayer.create()` method. Instead use an `AssetFileDescriptor` and set the data source after you've created the `MediaPlayer`

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button play36 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.threesix);

    String[] listOfFiles = new String[0];
    try {
        listOfFiles = getAssets().list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int itemIndex = (int) (Math.random() * listOfFiles.length);
    String file = listOfFiles[itemIndex];
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(file);

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    play36.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

    descriptor.close();
```

Comment: Still get this thing with the code you presented: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileDescriptor android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor()' on a null object reference`